Websocket (WSS) fails to send cookies when intercepting custom app-files protocol in electron
Websocket (WSS) fails to send cookies when intercepting custom app-files protocol
this is demo link
https://gist.github.com/z2014/0815b33d3ce8c700b63679d0519c1ab5
is electron not support intercept wesocket,and not modify request headers cookies?
session.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders(filter, async (details, callback) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
        const { requestHeaders } = details;
        console.log('cookies', details.url);
        requestHeaders.cookie = cookie;
        // 扩展origin和refer，应对可能的校验规则
        requestHeaders.origin = `https://${pageHost}` || requestHeaders.Origin || requestHeaders.origin || url.realOrigin;
        requestHeaders.referer = `https://${pageHost}`;
        callback({ requestHeaders });
    });

Intercept & reply to WSS requests in Electron
